# Can't deploy Django + Heroku. at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I'm having trouble deploying my first Django app to Heroku. It works well in development but I can't find (or understand) the issue in the log. I've checked multiple threads with the same H10 error but everyone seem to have a somehow different log and their solutions are not working on my end. Let me know if there is anything else aside from the following that I should include in order to understand what's going on.

**Full log:**

```
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390320+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390320+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390321+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390321+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390321+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390322+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390322+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390322+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390323+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390324+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390324+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390324+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390325+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390333+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'craigslist_clone'
2020-08-11T08:36:47.390551+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:47 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-08-11T08:36:47.442506+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-08-11T08:36:47.442581+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-08-11T08:36:47.540045+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-08-11T08:36:47.589027+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-11T08:36:47.591726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-11T08:36:52.986845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn craigslist_clone.wsgi`
2020-08-11T08:36:54.949245+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-08-11T08:36:54.949773+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:44861 (4)
2020-08-11T08:36:54.949871+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-08-11T08:36:54.954399+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960530+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960531+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960531+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960531+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960532+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960532+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960532+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960532+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960533+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960533+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960533+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960533+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960534+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960534+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960534+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960534+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960534+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960535+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960535+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960535+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960535+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960540+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'craigslist_clone'
2020-08-11T08:36:54.960717+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-08-11T08:36:54.981960+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987590+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987592+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987592+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987593+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987593+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987594+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987594+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987594+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987595+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987595+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987600+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987600+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987600+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987601+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987601+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987602+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987602+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987602+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987603+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987603+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987604+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987611+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'craigslist_clone'
2020-08-11T08:36:54.987736+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-08-11T08:36:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-11T08:36:55.093662+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-08-11T08:36:55.093752+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-11 08:36:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-08-11T08:36:55.157659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-08-11T08:36:55.193966+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-11T08:37:07.657451+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user mwoonky@gmail.com
2020-08-11T08:37:13.678634+00:00 heroku[run.6426]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-11T08:37:13.774667+00:00 heroku[run.6426]: Awaiting client
2020-08-11T08:37:13.797319+00:00 heroku[run.6426]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2020-08-11T08:37:20.153983+00:00 heroku[run.6426]: Process exited with status 0
2020-08-11T08:37:20.189249+00:00 heroku[run.6426]: State changed from up to complete
2020-08-11T08:37:26.966717+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-journey-70264.herokuapp.com request_id=f71ce6d3-dd74-4a25-8468-289bcda1f39f fwd="145.101.22.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-11T08:37:28.566366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-journey-70264.herokuapp.com request_id=dda4b09d-62cd-4cce-a613-181aa9a49d00 fwd="145.101.22.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-11T08:38:20.797118+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-journey-70264.herokuapp.com request_id=9fe9cfbe-ee30-41fe-83c8-34ce82b577b6 fwd="145.101.22.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-11T08:38:22.379610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-journey-70264.herokuapp.com request_id=b6ab19f3-131b-451f-83f0-a4f7149b39a6 fwd="145.101.22.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-11T08:39:14.019669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-journey-70264.herokuapp.com request_id=f75b7237-4cef-4546-ada6-4c604be042eb fwd="145.101.22.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-11T08:39:15.505950+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-journey-70264.herokuapp.com request_id=3e03d12f-8b60-4777-85fb-4a67fe3ccc4a fwd="145.101.22.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Procfile**

`web: gunicorn craigslist_clone.wsgi`

**This is my requirements.txt**

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.2.10
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
distlib==0.3.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
filelock==3.0.12
gunicorn==20.0.4
heroku==0.1.4
idna==2.10
pipenv==2020.6.2
psycopg2==2.8.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.10
virtualenv==20.0.30
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

**Settings.py also has the following included:**

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Try and deploy again. pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: Let me know. If it works!

Comment: craigslist_clone isn't in requirement.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'craigslist_clone'

craigslist_clone is not found if craigslist_clone is your local function the check the function call or if craigslist_clone is global python function then specify in requirement.txt

If problem exists share code file

Answer (score 0):

> Error: What error says is there is no module 'craigslist_clone'

As you have mentioned it works well in development and error occurs in deployment. So the error is not from any python function.

I recommend you to specify explicit dependency versions in your `requirements.txt` file. To update this file, you can use the `pip freeze` command in your active virtual environment(development) :

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```